# Set AVG result AS column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am running a query in SQL Server 2005. The query needs to have a column that consists of the same number the whole way down. The number is the avg of another row in the query. Here is what I have, maybe it will help make sense of what I am trying. This data has 'color' values and the 'DataExtraLineValue' the same the whole way down because the software that reads this query is spitting out a chart. Basically, why cant I run AVG(TagValueInteger) AS DataExtraLineValue

```
SELECT
      RecordedDateTime AS DataGroup,
      TagValueInteger AS DataBar,
      TagValueInteger AS DataLine,
      'Green' AS DataColor,
      'Avg' AS DataExtraLineLabel,
       AVG(TagValueInteger) AS DataExtraLineValue,
      'Blue' AS DataExtraLineColor
FROM tTagHistory
WHERE
      (TagHistoryDefinitionID = 2) AND
      (IsQualityGood = 1) AND
      (DeltaValueInteger <> 0) AND
      (TagValue > 4) AND
      (TagValue < 60) AND 
      (RecordedDateTime > (GetDate()-2))
ORDER BY RecordedDateTime DESC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that because there's no grouping.  Without grouping, your `AVG` is going to be the value for each row.  If you want the average for ALL values of that field for the whole table, you can make it a subquery:

```
SELECT ....
       (SELECT AVG(TagValueInteger) FROM tTagHistory) as DataExtraLineValue
       ....
```

Comment: This is perfect. The subquery is what I need because I do need that same value the whole way down! Thanks!

Comment: @Jake - happy to help.  Be careful with aggregates!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is like so:

```
SELECT 
  ....    
  AVG(TagValueInteger) over () AS DataExtraLineValue
  ....
```

Answer (score 1):

`AVG` is an aggregate function. Using aggregate functions implies grouping. You either aggregate values in the entire rowset or in groups. In the former case you cannot have non-aggregated columns (except for static values, like your `'Green'`, `'Avg'` ones), and in the latter case you must introduce the GROUP BY clause where you are to list all the columns that define groups: those will go non-aggregated in the SELECT list. Since your query does have some non-aggregated values, it's more likely the second case, and your query should then look somehting like this:

```
SELECT
      RecordedDateTime AS DataGroup,
      TagValueInteger AS DataBar,
      TagValueInteger AS DataLine,
      'Green' AS DataColor,
      'Avg' AS DataExtraLineLabel,
       AVG(TagValueInteger) AS DataExtraLineValue,
      'Blue' AS DataExtraLineColor
FROM tTagHistory
WHERE
      (TagHistoryDefinitionID = 2) AND
      (IsQualityGood = 1) AND
      (DeltaValueInteger <> 0) AND
      (TagValue > 4) AND
      (TagValue < 60) AND 
      (RecordedDateTime > (GetDate()-2))
GROUP BY RecordedDateTime, TagValueInteger
ORDER BY RecordedDateTime DESC
```

However, as per your post, it's even more likely that you want to retrieve both aggregated and non-aggregated values. In that case you need windowed aggregation. An aggregated function becomes a *windowed* aggregated function by adding the [`OVER` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) to it. In your particular case it should probably be like this:

```
SELECT
      RecordedDateTime AS DataGroup,
      TagValueInteger AS DataBar,
      TagValueInteger AS DataLine,
      'Green' AS DataColor,
      'Avg' AS DataExtraLineLabel,
       AVG(TagValueInteger) OVER () AS DataExtraLineValue,
      'Blue' AS DataExtraLineColor
FROM tTagHistory
WHERE
      (TagHistoryDefinitionID = 2) AND
      (IsQualityGood = 1) AND
      (DeltaValueInteger <> 0) AND
      (TagValue > 4) AND
      (TagValue < 60) AND 
      (RecordedDateTime > (GetDate()-2))
ORDER BY RecordedDateTime DESC
```

`AVG(TagValueInteger) OVER ()` returns the average value of `TagValueInteger` per the entire rowset. Alternatively you can modify the `OVER ()` clause so as to return different (possibly repeating) values per different groups, for example `` `AVG(TagValueInteger) OVER (PARTITION BY DataGroup) `` will return different average values each for different value of `DataGroup`. You can read more about it in the linked article.